# Set global margins (width) for pictures - different than text margins

Tags: graphics, margins

I have produced my `pdf` output from `tex` file and noticed that my pictures are not "correctly" included - their left margin corresponds to the left margin of the regular text, but the right margin in beyond my control and stands out:

[image]

To address this problem, I would like to make **all icnluded pictures be centered and NOT be subjected to any text margin settings** (they may exceed text margins, but symmetrically). Moreover, in my case, **it must be done via some global options at the beginning of the document** (NOT: in the document body, e.g. within `includegraphics` section).

Thank you in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: Your picture is too wide for the page: centring a picture that 'fits' is easy enough

Comment: you can use `\centering` in the figure and use `\width=1\textwidth` in the square brackets after `\includegraphics`. If you need something global, you can define a macro using `\def` to replace the usual `\includegraphics`.

Comment: I am also wondering what happened to second image on the right margin (with 'RStudio' title)?

Comment: (Well, on the picture I included in my post there is **one** image, which consists of two "Paint-sticked" screen shoots ;) )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I save (`\let`) a copy of `\includegraphics` to `\svincludegraphics` and then redefine it with

```
\renewcommand\includegraphics[2][]{\makebox[0pt]{\svincludegraphics[#1]{#2}}}
```

so that it appears to LaTeX as being centered about a zero-width box (I could make that a `\textwidth` box if I wanted).  As long as the `\includegraphics` usage is centered on a line by itself, it will freely extend past the margins, as needed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\let\svincludegraphics\includegraphics
\renewcommand\includegraphics[2][]{\makebox[0pt]{\svincludegraphics[#1]{#2}}}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[3]
\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=1.1\textwidth,height=1cm]{file}
\caption{My caption}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[4]
\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth,height=1cm]{file}
\caption{My caption}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[4]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 Your answer is shorter than mine and does basically the same. so I'll delete mine.

Comment: Perfect answer! Thank you a lot! I am a basic `TeX` user and wouldn't work it out for hours. It saved me a plenty of time! :)

Comment: @Marciszka You are most welcome.  I edited my solution once I realized that I did not need the `stackengine` package for this solution (part of an earlier attempt).  So you can remove that inclusion from your solution. [You'll find I use `stackengine` a lot, since I wrote it]